# Transform square to rectangle with natural sizes.

Tags: geometry

I'm newbie in math, 
in my play with math, I came across the following problem:

Let $A$ the area of square with sizes: $(l_1 = l_2) = \sqrt A$

How transform $(l_1,l_2)$ to $(l_1',l_2')$ where $(l_1',l_2') \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

ex) Consider the squares

> for
>   $A = 15 \implies (l_1,l_2) = \sqrt 15  = 3.87298334621 $

can then $l_1' = 5$ and $l_2' = 3$

> for $A = 221 \implies (l_1,l_2) = \sqrt {221} = 14.8660687473 $

can then  $l_1'= 13$ and $l_2' =17$

> for $A = 1619707 \implies (l_1,l_2)= \sqrt {1619707} = 1272.67709966$

can then $l_1'=4229$ and $l_2'= 383$

Is possible to write a algorithm to find this numbers using minimum of brute force ?

A hint please.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to factor $A$ into the pair of factors that are closest together (which will make them close to $\sqrt A$).  If $A$ is not too large, factoring is not hard-just have a list of primes handy and try them up the line.  Then if $A=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\dots p_n^{a_n}$ you can write $\log A = a_1 \log p_1+a_2 \log p_2 + \dots a_n p_n$ and you want to split the terms on the right into two groups whose sums are as equal as possible. Unfortunately, this is a version of the [Bounded Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is known to be hard in the general case.

Comment: Please, you can give me a little simulation ? Thanks so much. ^^

Comment: If $A=2520=2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot7$ we know that $2^3$ and $3^2$ are very close and $3^2 \gt 2^3$, so you would do $2^3\cdot 7=56$ and $3^2\cdot 5=45$.  But If you had $2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot1223\cdot 1229 \cdot 17393 \cdot 19103$ it isn't so obvious